# Git cherry pick commit from one repo to another repo

Tags: git, github, git-cherry-pick

So, there are two repositories - let's call them A and B. In repo A, there are four branches: dev, qa, uat, and prod. Repo B has three branches: qa, uat, and prod. I need to cherry-pick a commit from repo A's dev branch to repo B's qa branch. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you have a local repo that is a clone of one of them, add the other as a remote on that local repo and then do the cherry-pick.

Comment: An alternative is to use patches. Create a patch from some commit's diff in the first repo, then apply it on the other repo.